# How do I flip a curve/connector in drawio?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Given an isolated curve/connector as below, how can I flip or rotate it?

[image: Image of isolated curve connector in drawio]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot flip edges, only shapes.The only possibility is to "Reverse" edges.

Kind regards,

Comment: Thank you Marija.

Answer (score 3):

I have just found how to flip the line:

1. Select the line you want to flip.
2. Select the arrange column in the format panel (right of page by default, cmd+shif+p in macOS).
3. Select horizontal or vertical in the `flip` cell.

Not sure how to rotate with specific angle yet.